# TOAST MESSAGES NOT FIRING

Tags: lightning

I have a lightning component A , which fires a toast messages when a record gets saved.(The toast messages works perfectly when we save record independently without embedding it in an app)

**LIGHTNING COMPONENT A**

```
action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            helper.callSaveToast({
                "title": "Record Update",
                "type": "success",
                "message": " Records saved/updated sucessfully"
            });
            alert("Records saved/updated sucessfully");
            window.close();
        }
        else {
            this.handleException(component,response.getError());}
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Now i am embedding this lightning component inside a lightning APP. And when i launch the app and perform any save operation the toast messages doesn't fire.

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" access="GLOBAL" >
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:showToast" type="EVENT"></aura:dependency>
 <c:LIGHTNING COMPONENT A/>
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you embedding this application in a Visualforce page using Lightning Out?

Comment: Is this lightning App embedded in a VisualForce page using lighting out?

If you check out the documentation, it says that the force:showToast event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, Salesforce app, and Lightning communities. So if you are trying to use it in Lighting out, it will not work.
 
Also, this is simpler:

    `var toast= $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toast.setParams({
        'title': 'Success',
        'type': 'success',
        'mode': 'dismissable',
        'message': 'Some Message.'
    });
    toast.fire();`

Comment: @MitchSpano FYI: `$A.get('e.force:showToast').setParams({...}).fire();` The temporary variable is not necessary. Also, why'd you delete the answer? You are (mostly) correct; they're using a Lightning App, and that's not a supported container for force:showToast.

Comment: Fox, I deleted it because I thought it was more of a comment or additional question than an explicit answer. Also, I like doing the temporary variable and setting the params based on the return state, then at the bottom of the callback function I typically call fire().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

force:showToast requires the Lightning Experience, a Community, or the Salesforce app. It is not supported in Lightning Apps, Lightning Out, or Visualforce. Since you have code contained in a `<aura:application>`, the event can be fired, but there's nobody listening, so it does nothing.

You'd have to implement your own toast library to handle situations where you're using an unsupported experience. Try searching on a search engine for "github lightning toast component" or something similar, you should find some code to get you started.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. 

@sfdcfox - Thank you for your advise and will try and keep you posted on the outcome.